# Analysis of Algorithms Notation Confirmation

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'll go ahead and mention that this is homework, but I'm not seeking typical homework help. I'm just wanting confirmation on wording of the question. The question states that my algorithm should be linear in the number of vertices in the graph. I've never seen that wording, is that just saying my running time should be O(|V|)? If so I think I have my solution.

Comment: @vidit Thanks, I was hoping I would hear that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In analysis of algorithms, algorithms are categorized by efficiency as a function of their input size.

`O(|V|)` means that your algorithm must examine, or 'touch', every vertex in your graph. So yes, linear in the number of vertices means `O(|V|)`.

For reference, in Big `O`, `Ɵ`, or `Ω`; the two vertical bars mean *number of*. They are also used to denote *length of* in some proofs.

Comment: @Pinsickle No problem, if you are working with this type of stuff it might be worth it to purchase this book: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844 It is sort of the standard for analysis of algorithms and data structures.

Comment: `"must examine, or 'touch', every vertex"` - technically a bit of an over simplification / generalization. You *can* write an algorithm to process the first `|V|` *edges* (and never 'touch'ing a vertex), and this would also be `O(|V|)`. The important part is that is does a constant amount of work per vertex. Also, `"two vertical bars"` doesn't *just* mean cardinality (number of) in Big O, Ɵ, or Ω. You can use it just about anywhere else to indicate cardinality as well.

Comment: @Dukeling I made the answer simple on purpose, and usually `V` is used to represent vertex not edge., but I see your point.